# Calling Restful Service using JQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf-rest

Here's the service.

```
   [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{city}", ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   string FormatAddress(string city);
   public string FormatAddress(string city) {  return city; }
```

Here's the client.
Calling from the url like so `http://localhost:8210/formataddress/irvine`
returns the city name, as expected.

Calling from JQuery like so doesn't return success.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8210/formataddress/irvine",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: onError,
        success: onSuccess
    });

function onSuccess(data, status) {
    alert("inside onSuccess");
}

function onError(data, status) {
    alert("inside onError");
}
```

I've tried passing the city name like so data: `{"city" : "irvine"}` and 
various other tweaks to the `$.ajax` method parameters.

Any idea's how I can access the `inside onSuccess` message to display ?

BTW all the projects are in the same VS2008 solution.

Comment: Please edit your post and use the code formatting button.

Comment: Have you checked the response code to see if it's OK? (200, 304, etc). Also have you seen that in the request body the content is in fact there as you would expect?

Comment: Also, what is the content type of the response (check the response's headers)

Comment: Are you sure that `contentType` shouldn't be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for `GET` request?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following code before the ajax call.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```